# jquery drop not working on first time?

Tags: jquery

i am kind facing the weird issue. Drop event not working in first time, works good on second time.

my code:

```
$( document).ready( init());

function init() {
    $blueClone = null;
    var inYellow = false;

    $('.dragme').draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: 'move',
//        revert: true    // causes the dropped blue to zip back to it's source - whether dropped into the yellow or not
    });

    $('#grey').droppable({   

        // for any blue that gets dropped in grey
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if( ui.draggable.hasClass( 'canvas-element')) { 
                $blueClone = ui.draggable;
                $blueClone.remove();
            } else {
                $blueClone = ui.draggable.clone();    // create a new blue 
            }



            $('#yellow,#green').droppable( {    // for any blue that gets dropped in yellow        
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var $canvas = $(this);
                    if( !ui.draggable.hasClass('canvas-element')) {    // if the blue that has just been dropped was not already in yellow
                        $blueClone.addClass('canvas-element');
                        $blueClone.draggable({
//                            containment: '#yellow'    // ensures that once blue is in yellow, it remains contained in yellow
                        });
                        $canvas.append($blueClone);    // attach the new blue created above onto yellow
                        $blueClone.css({
                            left: (ui.position.left),
                            top: (ui.position.top),
                            position: 'absolute'
                        });
                    }    // if( !ui.draggable.hasClass('canvas-element'))
                }    // drop: function (event, ui)
            });    // $('#yellow').droppable(

        }    // drop
    });    // $( '#grey')





}
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/GRDww/155/

I have been sitting around on this bug for a while.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that makes the yellow and green boxes droppable is inside the `drop` handler for the grey box. So initially only the grey box is a drop target.

Then the first drop hits the grey box's drop handler, and only then do the yellow and green boxes become droppable.

If you move it outside the `drop` function, it works first time:

```
$('#grey').droppable( {
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      /*...*/
    }
}); // $('#grey')

$('#yellow,#green').droppable( {
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      /*...*/
    }
}); // $('#yellow,#green')
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRDww/156/